# Кнопки виде картинок

Tags: python, изображения, tkinter, button

Подскажите как мне справиться с поставленной задачей.
У меня программа из 3 экранов переключение между ними кнопками.
В первом окне две кнопки 0.5 и 0.7 это radiobutton из них я пытаюсь сделать виде картинок (самих бутылок) 
[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2ZVz.png)

Во втором окне я пытаюсь сделать несколько картинок с разными бутылками (например если пользователь нажмет на одну то выбирается определенная переменная и она будет работать в 3 окне) 
[image: Во втором окне]

В третем окне я уже отправляю данные в бд.
[image: В третем окне я уже отправляю данные в бд.]

1.Окне я выбрал вид бутылки
2.Выбрал название бутылки (по картинке)
3.В третем окне я уже все заливаю в бд.

Не могу разобраться со вторым окном, что бы там были бутылки виде картинок (нажал на ее она зажалась)
Мой код: https://gist.github.com/Liofan/9b531d8f572cd33913d1cbbcacd887bc

Пример как я пытаюсь сделать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1) Код нужно прямо в вопрос помещать 2) в гистах можно указывать формат файла и получить подсветку, переименуйте `two` в `two.py` 3) Предоставьте минимальный пример с проблемой

Comment: пытаюсь сделать кнопки виде картинок что бы пользователь мог на них нажать. и на какую нажал та будет активна и название будет записываться в бд

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Liofan/9b531d8f572cd33913d1cbbcacd887bc